# How to make my keyboard loads with out network access iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, keyboard

I've developed a custom keyboard for iOS 8 and I submitted that for review in App Store about 7 days ago.

But today they rejected my app and said that's because your app does not work without network access and it is against Guideline 25.5

But I've tried actually every other keyboard available on the App Store, and non of them loads with out granting "Allow Full Access". I've done every thing you can imagine, but non of them made my keyboard (or any other keyboard available on the App Store) loads with out granting "Allow Full Access".

I also created a completely new project, and add keyboard extension and tried to run it, but again, even that simple project (which I did not even add a line of code) did not load keyboard with out granting "Allow Full Access".

So if any one had similar problem, what should I do, to make my app loads keyboard with out granting "Allow Full Access".

Comment: "Allow full access" isn't anything to do with network access.  You need to test your keyboard with network disable (WiFi & cellular data off) and figure out why your keyboard doesn't work

Comment: @Paulw11 No, That's not, I turned on Airplane Mode and installed keyboard fresh, and after enabling "Allow Full Access" keyboard worked even offline.

Comment: Then I suggest you contact Apple and ask them the steps to reproduce the problem.